# Django Rest Framework (GET filter on ManyToMany field)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to figure out how to filter a ManyToMany field by value. In Django, it is as simple as queryset.filter(m2mfield__name), but I can't quite figure out what I am missing. I am using the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and the [DjangoFilterBackend](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#djangofilterbackend).

**Models:**

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

**Filters:**

```
import django_filters

class StateFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    cities = django_filters.CharFilter(
        name='cities__name',
        lookup_type='contains',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('name', 'cities')
```

**Serializers:**

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('name', )

class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cities = CitySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('name', 'cities')
        filter_class = StateFilter
```

**View:**

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from .serializers import StateSerializer

class StateList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    filter_fields = ('name', 'cities')
```

The output for ../api/states/ is currently:

```
 [
     "name": "Florida",
     "cities": [
          "name": "Tampa",
          "name": "St. Petersburg",
          "name": "Orlando"
     ],
     "name": "North Carolina",
     "cities": [
          "name": "Raleigh",
          "name": "Charlotte",
          "name": "Greensboro"
     ]
 ]
```

How can I filter the cities via a GET call by name such as:

> ../api/states/?cities=Charlotte

The result of the above should be:

```
 [
     "name": "North Carolina",
     "cities": [
          "name": "Raleigh",
          "name": "Charlotte",
          "name": "Greensboro"
     ]
 ]
```

Comment: Can you show your ViewSet ?

Comment: @Zulu, I have added the ViewSet as requested.

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'FILTER_BACKEND': 'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I found out what I was doing wrong. It was in the view. I had not declared filter_class on the view:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from .serializers import StateSerializer
from .filters import StateFilter

class StateList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    filter_fields = ('name', 'cities')
    filter_class = StateFilter  # This was missing
```

I accidentally placed it on the serializer instead.