# Django Rest Framework filterset on many to many field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to filter manytomany field by it's name field but I can't set it up properly. Could any body have a look at this?

**Models**

```
class Criteria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, primary_key=True)
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
```

**Views**

```
class CriteriaViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Criteria.objects.all()
    filter_class = CriteriaFilter
    filter_fields = ('tests',)


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return CriteriaSerializer
        return CriteriaDetailSerializer
```

**Filterset**

```
class CriteriaFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    test = django_filters.CharFilter(name="tests__name", lookup_type='contains')
    class Meta:
        model = Criteria
        fields = ('tests',)
```

**Serializers**

```
class CriteriaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tests = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    links = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Criteria
        fields = ('name', 'tests', 'links')

    def get_links(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return {
            'self': reverse('api:criterium-detail',
            kwargs={'pk': obj.pk},
            request=request),
        }
```

With the configuration above what I get on the URL:

> /api/criteria/?test=FB1400

is empty results array even though there is a number of Criteria containing addressed test:

```
HTTP 200 OK Content-Type: application/json Vary: Accept Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "count": 0,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": []
}
```

I was trying different lookups (exact, in, contains) as well as different values in `fields` but none of those works for me...
I was also wondering if I should set up django filter backend somewhere but I'm not sure how to do this and I don't know if it's necessary in this case.

Comment: In DRF 2.4.4, you have to specify `filter_backends` in the viewset like `filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved it, but this post is similar to this other which was solved by the way:

[Django Rest Framework (GET filter on ManyToMany field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943426/django-rest-framework-get-filter-on-manytomany-field)

Hope this helps.